# Operation not allowed on IsolatedStorageFileStream

Tags: windows-phone-7, isolatedstorage

I am reading XML file from Internet. I am writing it to isolated storage and I like to read  it after that.Here is the code

```
  IsolatedStorageFile isf=IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication();
    private void findNearestButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {

        findCity(isf);
    }

  private void findCity(IsolatedStorageFile isf)
    {
       filePath = AppResource.exchangeOfficesFile;

            if (!isf.FileExists(filePath.ToString()))
            {
                takeXMLOnLine(isf,filePath);
            }
            parseXMLfile(isf,filePath);

    }



 private void takeXMLOnLine(IsolatedStorageFile isf, string filePath)
    {
        System.Uri targetUri = new System.Uri(AppResource.exchangeOfficesURI);
        WebClient client = new WebClient();
        client.DownloadStringAsync(targetUri);
        client.DownloadStringCompleted += new DownloadStringCompletedEventHandler(client_DownloadStringCompleted);

    }



void client_DownloadStringCompleted(object sender, DownloadStringCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        using (IsolatedStorageFileStream rawStream = isf.OpenFile(filePath, FileMode.Create))
        {
            XmlWriterSettings settings = new XmlWriterSettings();
            settings.ConformanceLevel = ConformanceLevel.Auto;
            using (XmlWriter writer = XmlWriter.Create(rawStream, settings))
            {
                string xmlResponse = e.Result.ToString();
                xmlResponse = xmlResponse.Replace("&lt;", "<");
                xmlResponse = xmlResponse.Replace("&gt;", ">");
                writer.WriteString(xmlResponse);
                // Write the XML to the file.
                writer.Flush();
            }

        }
    }


 private void parseXMLfile(IsolatedStorageFile isf, string filePath)
    {

            using (IsolatedStorageFileStream str = isf.OpenFile(filePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
            {
                StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(str);
                string line;


                while ((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
                {

                    MessageBox.Show(line);


                }
                reader.Close();
            }
```

}

When I run the code I get Operation not allow on IsolatedStoreageFileStream error at this line

```
  using (IsolatedStorageFileStream str = isf.OpenFile(filePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
```

Could somebody help me?

Comment: Is there already a file with that name in existence, in isolated storage?

Comment: No there isn't. I run my app with one file name and !fileExist() is always true.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
using (IsolatedStorageFile rootStore = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication())
{
    using (IsolatedStorageFileStream fs = new IsolatedStorageFileStream(filePath,
                    System.IO.FileMode.Open, rootStore))
    {
        ... whatever you do with the file goes here
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If the file path has a sub directory, see if the directory exists. That could cause this problem.

Comment: It is not a subdirectory I have created it in IsolatedStorage

Answer (score 0):

Does the file exist when you try to read it? It looks like if the file doesn't exist, you start the download process (but do not wait for completion) and then try to read it.

So instead, something like:

```
private void findCity(IsolatedStorageFile isf)
{
    filePath = AppResource.exchangeOfficesFile;

    if (!isf.FileExists(filePath.ToString()))
    {
        takeXMLOnLine(isf,filePath);
    }
    else
    {
        parseXMLfile(isf,filePath);
    }
}

void client_DownloadStringCompleted(object sender, DownloadStringCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    using (IsolatedStorageFileStream rawStream = isf.OpenFile(filePath, FileMode.Create))
    {
        XmlWriterSettings settings = new XmlWriterSettings();
        settings.ConformanceLevel = ConformanceLevel.Auto;
        using (XmlWriter writer = XmlWriter.Create(rawStream, settings))
        {
            string xmlResponse = e.Result.ToString();
            xmlResponse = xmlResponse.Replace("&lt;", "<");
            xmlResponse = xmlResponse.Replace("&gt;", ">");
            writer.WriteString(xmlResponse);
            // Write the XML to the file.
            writer.Flush();
        }
    }

    parseXMLfile(isf,filePath);
}
```

Comment: It always says that the file does not exist and try to download it again and there is ObjectDisposeException was unhandled while creating the file...

Comment: I always check on button click if the file exist. If the file doesn't exist I use a function to download it.After that I call function for reading from the file. The problem is that I usually get Operation not allowed on IsoaltedStorageFileStream Exception. I delete the function for reading from the code and call only the writing first, and run the program there isn't any exception.Then I write again the function for reading and it works. Why the first way doesn't work?

Comment: Yes, but you don't wait for the download to complete, so your code is trying to read from a file that doesn't exist - if you compare with the versions I'd suggested, it calls back later, if it had to cue a download.