# IsolatedStorageFileStreamException

Tags: windows-phone-7, isolatedstorage

I am reading file from Internet asynchronous on button click and I write it to txt file.I always check on button click if the file exist. If the file doesn't exist I use a function to download it.After that I call function for reading from the file. 
The problem is that I usually get Operation not allowed on IsoaltedStorageFileStream Exception. I delete the function for reading from the code and call only the writing first, and run the program there isn't any exception.Then I write again the function for reading and it works.
Why the first way doesn't work?

Comment: Lock around your file read/writes

Comment: possible duplicate of [Operation not allowed on IsolatedStorageFileStream](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10956997/operation-not-allowed-on-isolatedstoragefilestream)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with access to the file. If your async operation opens the file and while it still writes you want to read form it. This is concurrency issue. Add some kind of locking to the logic, even a simple boolean flag is good enough.

```
private canRead = false;
```

And when app finishes reading set it to true. Then in your reading logic

```
if(canRead)
{
     //read file
}
```

Other option is to hide the button and show it when the download is finished.